# Is this a good way to categorize items into "today" and "yesterday" sections, and how can I optimize it?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am receiving some data from an API that includes a creation date. My initial approach was to create a function that checks if 24 hours have passed since creation. If not, I would use a foreach loop in the view to iterate through the data and check if each item was created within the last 24 hours. Based on this, I decide where to display the data. However, this approach results in redundant checks, as the condition is within the foreach loop, and if I want to display a message like "No information for today," it gets displayed as many times as there are items in the model. Is there a more efficient way to achieve this categorization and avoid redundant checks?

```
struct TestView: View {
@StateObject var viewModel: ViewModel = ViewModel()

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            HStack {
                Text("Today")
                    .font(.ubuntu(name: .ubuntuBold, size: 14))
                    .foregroundColor(Color.gray.opacity(0.6))
                    .padding(.vertical, 15)
                Spacer()
            }
            ScrollView(showsIndicators: false) {
                if let history = viewModel.history?.data?.data {
                    ForEach(history.prefix(2), id: \.self) { item in
                        if !viewModel.isMoreThan24HoursAgo(item.createdAt ?? "N/A") {
                            HistoryCard(historyModel: item)
                        } else {
                            Text("No recent history added.")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            HStack {
                Text("Yesterday")
                    .font(.ubuntu(name: .ubuntuBold, size: 14))
                    .foregroundColor(Color.gray.opacity(0.6))
                    .padding(.vertical, 15)
                Spacer()
            }
            ScrollView(showsIndicators: false) {
                if let history = viewModel.history?.data?.data {
                    ForEach(history.prefix(2), id: \.self) { item in
                        if viewModel.isMoreThan24HoursAgo(item.createdAt ?? "N/A") {
                            HistoryCard(historyModel: item)
                        } else {
                            Text("No recent history added.")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        
        Spacer()
    }
}
}
```

And this is function:

```
func isMoreThan24HoursAgo(_ dateString: String) -> Bool {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
    
    guard let date = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString) else {
        return false
    }
    
    let calendar = Calendar.current
    let now = Date()
    let components = calendar.dateComponents([.hour], from: date, to: now)
    
    if let hours = components.hour, hours > 24 {
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't tell if "No recent history added." until *after* you've checked all of the items.

Comment: _"...some data from an API..."_, if the data is in json format you should decode the date to a `Date` directly imo.

Comment: Yes, data is in JSON.... date is in this format `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ`

Comment: It's probably better to check the dates and validate the age in your view model than in the view. One approach could be to use two computed properties, one where you use `.filter` to get the ones newer than 24 hours and one property that returns the ones older than 24 hours.

Comment: If all of your dates are in ISO8601 format like that, you can decode them directly into a date by setting `decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .iso8601`. This will give you dates to work with like @JoakimDanielson has commented.